# ReactJS/JavaScript: Access query results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After I execute a query in the console I can see: `{data:{action: [...]}`.  How can I assign that data to a variable in a React component?

Trying this but it is not working:

```
class MyGraph extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      this.state = {
            nodes: this.data
```

Comment: how would you get the data?

Comment: That is what I am trying to figure out. I can see the data in console but don't know how to access it.

Comment: What do you mean by "access a query in the console"? What is the query? Why can't you just put the same code directly into your React component?

Comment: share the whole component

Comment: if you can see it in console, try to find the console.log() statement that is putting it there. also, there is a nice React extension for Chrome browser that can be helpful for this sort of thing.

Comment: So you print this.data in the console? And what do you want to assign to this.state.nodes, the value of data (which is { action: [...]} ?

Comment: In a separate component I am trying to use the data to generate a graph.  Earlier today this is what I posted but got no replies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886083/neo4j-react-parsing-neo4j-results-for-use-in-react

Answer (score 1):

Have some falsy or empty initial value for `state.node`. Then fetch the data in `componentDidMount` - on success, update `state.node` with your actual data. That data can also be passed down to child components. Example:

```
class MyGraph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nodes: null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // w/e your fetch function is. I'm assuming your method uses promises.
    fetchDataSomehow().then((response) => {
      this.setState({nodes: response.data}) // or whatever property has the nodes
    })
  }

  render() {
    const nodes = this.state.nodes;

    return (
      <LoadingIcon isVisible={!nodes}>
        {(nodes || []).map((node) => (
            <MyCircle key={node.someUniqueId} node={node} /> // access `node` inside the `<MyCircle />` component using `this.props.node`
          ))}
      </LoadingIcon>
    )
  }
}
```

You'll need to handle what happens/renders while the data is still loading (e.g the made-up `<LoadingIcon />` component).

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do with this and let you know how it goes.